# Android SD card writing, Permission Denied

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am trying to write a file to SDCard with below Code (permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` already set in manifest.xml).
Upon execution of `nmea_file.createNewFile();` it throws exception with `Permission Denied`.

Any guesses why would this be happening?

```
if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
  {
     Log.d(TAG, "Sdcard was not mounted !!" ); 
  }
else
  {
    File nmea_file; 
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    FileWriter nmea_writer = null;
    try {
        nmea_file = new File(root,"NMEA.txt");
        if(!nmea_file.exists()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "File Doesn't Exists!");
                nmea_file.createNewFile();
            }
        nmea_writer = new FileWriter(nmea_file);
        nmea_writer.append(nmea);
        nmea_writer.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write", e);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (nmea_writer != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                nmea_writer.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Exception closing file", e);
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using sharedUerId to system?

Answer (score 31):

Add to manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I hope you read the question clearly, he said he had this permission in manifest already.

Answer (score 20):

It may happen if SD card is blocked for some operations, like:

1. Preparing to dismount SD card from slot
2. Device connected to PC as external USB drive

Comment: Foolishly forgot that my SD card was mounted as well, thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 12):

You might want to check that you have access to SDCARD. Here is how you can do it in code:

```
if(!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
    Toast.makeText(this, "External SD card not mounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that your uses-sdk statement can effect you ability to write to the SD card(!).

My AndroidManifest.xml had the following:

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

And I could write to the SD card without any problems even though I had not declared android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

When I changed my uses-sdk statement to:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="9" minSdkVersion="8" />
```

All my SD card writes failed with a permission denied! Granted that android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE should have been declared, but why with one uses-sdk statement it worked and the other it did not?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether sdcard is **mounted** or not if you are checking in emulator. Also dont foget to give some size for sdcard at the time of creating the emulator.  Then you need to add 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
in your manifest.

Comment: API Reference for checking mounts state here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html