# file not found exception android fileoutput stream

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to download xml from a url.
But I am getting `java.io FileNotFound sdcard.cellofest.xml Permission Denied`.
Last line is generating the error.
I have checked Google and found a lot of fixes, but none solved my problem.

I do have the Write External Storage permission in the AndroidManifest.

```
URL url = new URL("http://test.com/itsp/events/celloFest.xml");

// Create the new connection
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Set up some things on the connection...
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

// and connect!
urlConnection.connect();


// Set the path where we want to save the file.
// In this case, save it on the root directory of the
// SD card "\"
Log.d("xml download," , "just before downloading");
File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

// Create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename,
// Chich we want to save the file as.
Log.d("xml download" , "Sd card root found");
File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"cellofest.xml");
Log.d("xml download" ,"fest.xml created.");

//this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SD card writing, Permission Denied!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506612/android-sd-card-writing-permission-denied)

Comment: Which android version do you use? Real device or emulator?

Comment: Try `if (!SDCardRoot.exists()) return errormessage` and `if (!SDCardRoot.canWrite()) return sorry cannot write`. Try also `canRead()`.

Comment: What is the value of SDCardRoot.getAbsolutePath() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do have the permissions set.
i found the fix.
my sdcard has memory 200Mb which may be too much.
changed it to 20Mb and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a file before you can use it.  A quick fix would be as follows.

```
// Create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename,
// Chich we want to save the file as.
Log.d("xml download" , "Sd card root found");
// File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"cellofest.xml");
File file = File.createTempFile("cellofest", "xml", SDCardRoot);
Log.d("xml download" ,"fest.xml created.");
```

This instantiates *and* creates your File variable.

Comment: IOException can be a variety of things.  Give the description.

Comment: 06-18 23:15:21.588: W/System.err(637): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
06-18 23:15:21.588: W/System.err(637):  at java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method)
06-18 23:15:21.588: W/System.err(637):  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1160)
06-18 23:15:21.588: W/System.err(637):  at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1224)

Comment: Not needed. new FileOutputStream will create the file.

Comment: Well, that really only leaves me to conclude that he doesn't have permission to write to the SD card

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to have Write-Permissions to SD card. Make sure you declared permission like below in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <manifest ...>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    </manifest>
```

If you already have it declared, the verify you SD-Card is inserted into the device & is mounted. Then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
String responseString = RequestMgr.GetWebSource("http://www.test.com/itsp/events/celloFest.xml");
File localConfigfile = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "cellofest.xml");
    if (localConfigfile.exists()) {
                        localConfigfile.delete();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(localConfigfile);
                            out.write(responseString.getBytes());
                            out.flush();
}
```

RequestMgr.GetWebSource is just my own function to get the response from URL. So it is not a java function.

```
public static String GetWebSource(String url)
{
    HttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    //
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient1.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return out.toString();
}
```