# create a pdf file in the SD card in Android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a PDF file and put it in the SD Card I downloaded the library iText to do this and I imported to my project but there still have a problem in this line :

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
```

It tells me that `com.itextpdf.text.Document` collides with another import statement 
there is my code :

```
String loan_principal = rslt_loan_principal.getText().toString();
String dsr = rslt_dsr.getText().toString();
String flat_rate = rslt_flat_rate.getText().toString();
String ins_amount = rslt_installement_amount.getText().toString();

try
{
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/HomeFinance.pdf"));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Loan Principal : "+String.valueOf(loan_principal)));
    document.add(new Paragraph("DSR : "+String.valueOf(dsr)+ "%"));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Flat Rate  : "+String.valueOf(flat_rate)+ "%"));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Installment Amount : "+String.valueOf(ins_amount)+ "%"));
    document.close();
    Log.d("OK", "done");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (DocumentException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am not able to find the problem with this.

Comment: Post full activity code..including imports

Comment: Did you build the library file properly.for save as pdf file refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117085/how-to-save-the-layout-view-as-image-or-pdf-to-sd-card-in-android)

Comment: I just posted the imports that T have I can't find why there is a probléme with import com.itextpdf.text.Document; I added itext library but it still tell me that "com.itextpdf.text.document collides with another import statement " I can't no where is the problem

Comment: "I just posted the imports that T have" >> where ?

Comment: import android.provider.DocumentsContract.Document;import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

Answer (score 0):

Use this to retrieve the FileOutputStream, works for me:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + File.separator + <your package name here>);
folder.mkdirs();
File file;
try {
    file = new File(folder, "HomeFinance.pdf");
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: I judt tried this but I have FileNotFoundException can you help me !

Comment: Is the IOException thrown, too?

Comment: I have one message that tell me it is FileNotFoundException there is no IOException !

Comment: it said also "Permission denied"

Comment: Do you have the permission set that Metaphore mentioned?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: I already added this line to manifest.xml but I still have the same problem

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506612/android-sd-card-writing-permission-denied) might help you further. Make sure your SD car is mounted on your device.

Comment: Tha?!nk you very much it works :) can I ask you one more think how toverifie the content of the pdf file after his creation

Comment: Nice :) Don't forget to accept my answer (click the tick left of it). Sorry, no idea, but feel free to post that in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I used but still have the same problem !!